# 12V Car headlight halogens vs. 240V mains golf balls (longevity)

Tags: mains, automotive, reliability

The halogen headlights on my car must be about ten years old; I've never changed them and they put up with vibration, extremes of temperature etc.

Yet the 40W mains ones in my house (normally dimmed) typically last probably ~3 months before failing.

Is there any reason for this? Are automobile bulbs made to a much higher spec, and if so is it possible to get household bulbs made to this spec?

I just hate throwing out perfectly good glass and metal on a regular basis!

Cheers in advance if anyone can impart any wisdom on this.

Comment: Lower voltage means thicker filament which is mechanically stronger.

Comment: so, dimming might simply also make a difference here. And, I don't know where you reside, but at least in the EU incandescent light bulbs are being phased out, and you can now get pretty reliable LED bulbs for acceptable prices.

Comment: also, from my memory, 3 months does seem a bit short. Maybe switch bulb supplier, or maybe look into sources of voltage spikes in your grid.

Comment: @Transistor (good user name by the way!) That's interesting regarding the filament, I hadn't thought of that but yes boils down to R=V/I. I wonder if you can get small Stepdown transformers so I can use a car bulb?

Comment: @Marcus yes I'm aware of LED equivalents however I've never had much luck with them, multiple issues with one or more of (lack of dim-ability, flickering, awful colour temperature, expensive..)

Comment: @user233006 you don't need to use car equipment, home low-voltage halogen systems have been on the market and standardized since the early 1980s, and thus super cheap. They've fallen out of grace lately, because they are only slightly more efficient than their non-halogen high-voltage incandescent sisters. (again, you'll need a special dimmer, no matter what you do. If you're not satisfied with color temperature and dimming behaviour, you might need different LED bulbs – there's *really* terrible ones, especially in the least cost end of things, I can fully sympathize)

Comment: Most common tungsten failure modes are : overtemp in enclosure, fragility of filament due to surge current and vibration from any forces and resonance

Answer (score 1):

Dimming halogen lamps [inhibits the halogen cycle](https://www.topbulb.com/blog/dimming-alters-halogen-cycle/) that returns tungsten to the filament so you don't necessarily get the life extension you're expecting, especially if you run them many hours a day. You'll see the envelope getting dark prematurely as well.

Your automotive bulbs are either on or off, so when they're on the envelope temperature rises to an appropriate level for the halogen cycle.

Automotive operating duty cycles are usually very low in comparison to many other situations. 100,000 km on a car at an average of 45km/h is only 2200 hours. If you don't have daytime running lights the duty cycle will be lower again.

I recall the halogen headlight bulbs in cars (eg. 9004) were quite poor in lifetime when daytime running lights were first mandated here in Canada back around 1990 (my 1991 car had the lights replaced several times, and almost exactly at the same time- the Japanese manufacturing was very precise) and they managed to improve the lifetime- and the bulbs lasted a reasonable length of time per pair.

Presumably jurisdictions that didn't have daytime running lights (or used some kind of auxiliary lighting to meet the requirements) benefited greatly from whatever improvements they made.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, lower voltage means thicker filament which is mechanically stronger.

> Yet the 40W mains ones in my house (normally dimmed) typically last probably ~3 months before failing.

I have noticed that incandescent bulbs on a rotary dimmer circuit will last indefinitely. The bulb's cold resistance can be one fifth or even one tenth of the hot resistance so the inrush current is very high and you will probably, on reflection, remember several occasions when the bulbs failed with a pop on switch on. The rotary dimmer gives a soft start and the filament warms up in the time taken to rotate so any inrush current is greatly reduced.